# Nemesis Engine: ERROR(2006): Missing behavior file

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I've been trying to find out how to get Nemesis Engine to work properly, but when I update, I get the following error message: "ERROR(2006)". How do you fix this?

> Initializing engine update
>
> ERROR(2006): Missing behavior file. The behavior file name must be in this format (`"Nemesis_<filename>.xml"`) and it must be located in the same path as the hkx counterpart. Please contact the mod author.
> File: scripts
>
> Failed to update engine

<sup>[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbUR1.png)</sup>

I've searched and found out that Error 2006 occurs when a creature mod is missing or something.

My mods are:

- (DMC) The Ultimate Dodge Mod Reanimated
- (Part 1) SSE Engine Fixes for 1.5.39 - 1.5.97
- 120 FPS User Interface 1.2
- 3PCO - 3rd Person Camera Overhaul
- 3rd Person Camera Stagger Remover
- 9.0.1 A quality World Map
- Address Library for SKSE Plugins - All in one (SE)
- Aim Fix
- Animation Limit Crash Fix
- Animation Motion Revolution
- Another Vampire Leather Armor
- Arvak Replace SE
- Bash Behaviours Overhaul
- Better Jumping AE
- Better Third Person Selection (AE-SE)
- Bodyslide and Outfit Studio
- Book of SHadows
- BTPS - Nordic UI
- CBBE 3BA (3BB)
- Cloaks and Capes
- Compass Navigation Overhaul
- Condtional Armor Type Animation
- Contextual Crosshair
- Crosshair-ALigned Crossbow
- DAR - Dynamic Swimming
- Daring Lunar Guard Armor
- Detection Meter
- Diverse Dragon SE
- Dynamic Animation Replacer 1.1.0 SSE
- eFPS - Exterior FPS Boost
- Enhanced Volumetric Lightning and Shadows (EVLAS)
- ER moveset collection (MCO)
- Fairskin Complexion for CBBE V11.1
- Faster Horses V_1_1
- FileAccess Interface for SE Scripts - FISSES
- Fixnotes For SkyUI Skyrim SE 1.5.97
- Footprints 1.6.1
- Footprints and Sand Patch FOMOD 0.9
- Fores New Idles in Skyrim SE
- Gesture Animation Remix (DAR)
- Goetia Animations - Conditional Shouts
- Handguns of Skyrim 2.1.1
- Heavyblade Power attack SE
- IFrame Generator RE
- Immersive Citizens - AI Overhaul
- Improved Alternate Conversation Camera AE
- Infinity Dodge
- Infinity UI
- Inigo_V2.4C
- JContainers SE
- Jumping Attack Main File
- Kalilies Brows
- KS Hairdos SSE
- Lein's Perhaps Realistic NPCs - AIO
- Leviathan Animations(Sprint,Two handed stance, normal attack high stance, power attack for high stance, male walk and run)
- Liliths Eviscerator
- Lore Friendly Guns of Skyrim
- Lunar Guard 1k Textures
- Lunar Guard 3BA
- Lutsmord Vampire Armour - SSE CBBE
- Maximum Carnage ML Edition
- MCM Helper SE
- MfgFix
- Minecraft Diamond Sword - SE
- More informative Console 1.1.0
- Nemesis Creature Behavior Compatibility
- Nemesis Unlimited Behaviour Engine
- No Recoil
- Nordic UI
- Nordic-ish
- Onhit Animations Framework - NG
- Payload Interpreted
- Powerofthree's Tweaks
- Precision
- Script Free Flinching
- Script Free Behaviour Staggerlock
- Serana Dialogue Add-on
- Serana Lustmord Armor Outfit Patch
- Simple Sprint Dodge animation Replacer
- SkyHUD
- Skyrim Priority SE AE
- Skyrim Script Extender 64
- SkyUI -Ghost item Bug Fix
- SkyUI_5_2_SE
- slightly Better Rock Cairns
- Smooth Random Jump Animation REwork
- Smooth Random Sprint Animation
- Smooth Weapon jump Animation
- SmoothCam
- Smoothcam - Modern Camera Preset
- Spell Perk Item Distributor
- SSE Display Tweaks
- The Eyes of Beauty
- The paarthurnax Dilemma
- TK Dodge RE
- Tk Dodge SE
- TH dodge replace to Step dodge
- True Directional Movement
- TruHUD 1.1.8
- TUDMPatcher
- UIExtensions v1-2-0
- Ultimate Combat SE
- Unofficial Skyrim Edition Patch
- Valhalla Combat
- Vanargand Animations (Crossbows, Dual wield atacks, one handed mid stance, one handed normal attack, one handed power attacks, sneak crossbows, sneak walk and run)
- Vigilant SE-AE v171
- Violens
- Visual Animated Enchants V.2
- Vivid Weathers- Definitive Edition
- Water for ENB
- Wildcat - Combat of Skyrim
- XP32 Maximum Skeleton Special Extended

[image]

[image]

These are just the folders under my meshes all of them works and there's only the arvak creature mod here.

Comment: From the nemesis creature behavior compatibility's post: "***NEMESIS IS NOT FULLY COMPATIBLE WITH CREATURES** This don't make Creature sex/FNIS animations work with Nemesis, this only allows behaviour modders to do creature behaviour edits*" I understand that as any mod that'd add creature should create behavior file that's compatible with nemesis engine, and I am guessing that your mod(s) are not compatible with it. Might be wrong though. And I won't be digging which mod is causing that.

Comment: the thing is though I have only 2 creature mods diverse dragons and arvak replace but even if i disable thos mods or even if  I disable all of the mods except nemesis ofc I still get the same error

Comment: My hypothesis was wrong then. Have you tried to reinstall the mods in question? A [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/nfgx12/comment/gzjk42b/) claims that reinstalling the mod(s) and rebooting their PC fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you search your installation folder for a "scripts" file? I don't remember Skyrim having a non-extension file like that. That might go a long way to indicate potential incompatible mods.

Comment: @Joachim: There is normally a subdirectory with that name under the top level (data) directory. But Nemesis should be looking somewhere under the meshes subdirectory, I would tend to think, so it should not be able to find the scripts subdirectory at all (assuming all mods were installed correctly!).

Comment: @Kevin I know, but I doubt it checks for the mere existence of a folder and crashes if it cannot find it :)

Comment: @Joachim: That's not what I meant. I'm suggesting that some mod has been incorrectly installed, such that its top-level scripts directory has somehow ended up under the meshes directory, where Nemesis can find it and complain that it doesn't know what a "scripts" is or how to deal with it.